# Airport Extreme, Apple TV line-of-sight

Tags: wifi, appletv, airplay, streaming

I have an Apple TV (3rd Gen A1427), connected to my Airport Extreme (6th Gen).

I often stream music from iTunes on my retina MacBook Pro. The Apple TV, Airport and MBP are all connected on the same WiFi in an open plan lounge, dining, kitchen room. The TV, Apple TV and Laptop are at one side of the room, the Airport on the other, the only physical object between the Apple TV and Airport is a couch. The room would probably be less than 20m wide.

What I'm finding, if I walk or stand between the line of sight between Apple TV and Airport, the stream drops out.

Has anyone had this same experience with a similar set up?

Comment: what are you wearing? a armor ?

Comment: No, lol. Normal clothes.

Comment: Using 2.4 ghz or 5ghz?  and what other nearby networks are using the same channel?

Comment: 2.4 and 5Ghz, no channel overlap that I can see.

Tried pinging Apple TV from laptop while issue was taking place:

Comment: Lots of packets being dropped.